# Looking for ways to create a discord bot that grabs specific info from an API using commands

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title says I'm currently in the works of creating a discord bot that tracks fuel prices using the "Gas Tracker" API from collectapi. It's been a very long time since I've messed around in any coding language so I want to start from scratch to refresh all of my knowledge. I'm looking to see if anyone could suggest solutions as I can't really figure out how to grab specific information from the API via a command while also having the bot actively change the request to the API depending on which state they pick. I am practically a newbie programmer so make sure to go easy on me

So far I've only tried calling the API via a Python script that just requests information about one specific state. Not exactly sure how to go about making it so that a user could do ":tracker (gas type) (state)" and have it grab specific information from the API such as gas price, state name, type of gas. I'm really interested in learning Python and many other languages so any help is appreciated!